# How do I create Lucene index for Mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, lucene, full-text-search

I have this table Items in MySQL,

```
ItemId | ItemName| Category | Description | price | bidderCount
```

How do I create Lucene index for this table, so I can search if there are terms that I want to know are in the ItemName Or Description?

```
public class Indexer {
    public Indexer() {}
    public static IndexWriter indexWriter;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String usage = "java Indexer";
    rebuildIndexes("indexes");
    }
    public static void insertDoc(IndexWriter i, String doc_id, String line){
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new TextField("doc_id", doc_id, Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("line", line,Field.Store.YES));
    try { i.addDocument(doc); } catch (Exception e) {  e.printStackTrace(); }
}
    public static void rebuildIndexes(String indexPath) {
    try {
        Path path = Paths.get(indexPath);
        System.out.println("Indexing to directory '" + indexPath + "'...\n");
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(path);
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new SimpleAnalyzer());
        //IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
        //IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new EnglishAnalyzer());
        IndexWriter i = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
```

I can do it to build index for text i inserted, but have not idea how to make the database as a flat document so I can build the lucene index for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using jpa?

Comment: If you need a "flat file", consider doing `SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '...' FROM tbl;`